# Is the iOS Local Notification Limit Per Day?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, usernotifications

I'm working on an app where I need to send a good amount of notifications to the user daily. Around 5-40 depending on the user.

I'm using local notifications to send it, but I know there is a 64 notification limit. Does this mean 64 notifications per day, or in total?

Comment: Are you using `UILocalNotification`, or the `UserNotifications` framework? You should prefer the latter (though it doesn't change the limit).

Comment: I am using UILocalNotification. It is deprecated now though. Should I change it?

Comment: If you're just starting implementation, yes, absolutely, unless you plan to support iOS 9.

Comment: Just updated my post with the code that I am using. How do you suggest I update this to the UserNotifications. Not really planning on supporting iOS 9. Thanks!

Comment: The conversion to `UNNotificationRequest` instead of `UILocalNotification` is straightforward. Look at `UNMutableNotificatonContent`. But please don't ask more than one thing in a question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It means simultaneously **scheduled** for future delivery. You can send as many as you want per day, provided they don't overlap.

If you add more than 64 requests (under `UserNotifications`) or scheduled (under `UIApplication`/`UILocalNotification`), the older ones will be dropped and not delivered.

Comment: I am currently scheduling the notifications to repeat every day, wouldn't this imply infinite scheduled notifications? So would it not deliver them?

Comment: It only depends on how many are on the scheduled list at any given time.

Comment: @JoshCaswell is this documented somewhere?

Comment: The count won't be different for different iOS versions? @jscs

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately iOS limits the local schedule notification up to 64. May be to prevent this issue can schedule first group of notification initially and then schedule another group when launch the app next time.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere in apple docs?

Comment: Source would be appreciated

Comment: Follow this apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalnotification